# fetching fields using Sharepoint search Api

Tags: search, office-365, rest, api, search-api

I have a content type called `News Item`

Below is my Search Api query

```
http://spsite/sites/Intranet/_api/search/query?querytext='ContentType:News*'&selectproperties='Title,IsPromoted'
```

I am trying to retrieve a field called IsPromoted which is a boolean field. I created a Managed property and mapped it to this column. But the column is not bringing any results

[image]

Comment: Is the content is Crawled..?

Comment: yeah I mapped them more than 10 hours ago. Its  office365 so crawl should have happened

Answer (score 0):

Go to your search schema on the Search Admin page.  Look for the "searchable" checkbox on that property and check it.